# Mailing - "Send Test" button not a button

Tags: civimail

When trying to send a test mailing, the preview and test email box appears to be improperly drawn and the "Send Test" button doesn't appear to work.
I tried upgrading CiviCRM (from 4.6.2 to 4.6.4) but the problem persists.

CiviCRM 4.6.4, Wordpress 4.2.1, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6.9-1, Mariadb 10.0, Debian Wheezy/Sid hybrid

I notice this was an issue in the beta forums previously
http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,33598.msg142461.html#msg142461

Any ideas how to fix it?

[image: screencap]

Comment: Which browser are you using? A trick I try is to "Inspect element" or similar. Then the "web developer debugger" will show any problems in the HTML/CSS. I find that the CMS-template sometimes seems to screw up things like this.

Comment: They look like disabled buttons to me. Are you sure that you've completed all the required fields?

Comment: Agree with above, scrolling up on the page may show the 'message' such as 'zero contacts' or 'missing token'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are disabled. Notice that the "Next" button is also disabled. This means that you have not completed all required fields for your mailing. Please review that you have:

- A subject
- Recipients
- Content
- Required 'opt out' tokens

Answer (score 0):

They're disabled because you haven't completed all the required actions yet.

Have you remembered to include the the mandatory address and opt-out tokens in the body of your email?

You need to include:

```
{domain.address}
```

And at least one of the following:

```
{action.optOutUrl}

{action.unsubscribeUrl}​​​​​​​
```

The other thing to check is that you have a mailing list selected. It's silly but CiviMail requires one even when you're just sending a test to a single email, so it's worth having a generic 'test' mailing list set up for this purpose (that you can then replace with the 'real' mailing list before you send).

Answer (score 0):

I found a few more situations that the greyed out button can appear which may be less than obvious

- if there is no Resubscribe Msg set on the Response tab (no alert is currently provided
- if you put in a Subject, but then decide to switch to using a Template that has no Subject set